# Dojo form with ajax/dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

I am working on a DOJO form, and looking to create the base for basic ajax elements.

It will be a multi-tabbed form - with the dynamic fields being created/populated through ajax.

Is there an easier way of making the form more object orientated - where perhaps if a dynamic field is expected to appear under a parent - the api url is part of a data attribute of that field? What is the best practice for dyanmic forms like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/aGCFs/297/

```
on(dom.byId("getJson"), "click", function (e) {

            dojo.xhrGet({
        url: "https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos",
        handleAs: "json",
        load: function (newContent) {
            console.info("JSON loaded from server:  ", newContent);
        },
        error: function () {}
    });
console.log("getJson button was clicked!");
        });
```

My latest code is here - http://jsfiddle.net/aGCFs/312/

I am using a dojo.place to dynanmically add a dropdown html markup - as the site is likely to pick up the markup for a prepopulated drop downs from transforming xml to html - my remaining issue now though is how do I invoke the select box generated dynamically?

```
dojo.place('<select data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select"><option>test1</option><option>test2</option></select>', "div1", "");
```

Comment: Is this recommended - to seperate out the json callbacks - http://jsfiddle.net/aGCFs/298/

Comment: I've added two functions to create a dynamic text field and selectbox - http://jsfiddle.net/aGCFs/305/

Comment: How would I invoke html that is brought in via ajax to generate it as proper dojo form elements?